# Can I delete Spring log file?

Tags: spring, logging, amazon-ec2

I'm not very familiar with Spring log.

The log file is getting huge (>100GB), need to be deleted. I assume a new log file will be created after deletion, but not sure if it will bring any new problem. How can I delete it safely?

Also, how to configure to create a new log file every week?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Which logging framework are you using ? log4j or logback or any other ?

Comment: Not Log4j or logback. It's default of Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be deleted, then restart the API.